# Is there a way I can design the form 5 times without add 5 different form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have new Very large project  my problem 
 I have 5 different users in the program (admin - user -account - admin_account-reception) and if i use visible = false for the tools to hides it , the design  of the program becomes very ugly. Is there a way to save more than one design for the same form without changing the code?
By the way No code 
I'm just looking for the idea 
So I can never repeat the same form 5 times it 's already large in size and I do not want to make it bigger

Comment: Your Form could have different *Panels*, some of which may only be visible to specific *accounts*. See the TabControl component, for example. Or you could have Buttons used to show specific Panels (literally Panel controls) and you could show/hide these Buttons as required, making the Panels accessible only to some *type* of User. Just some suggestions, to avoid the multiplications of Forms on a user basis. It'll never end. The question is probably too broad.

Comment: "By the way, no code.." is going to be a tall order! ;) Jimis idea of panels would be the best, then you are just hiding and showing panels, short of that, you would in theory need to show/hide each control as needed. Is there a reason why you cannot use 5 different forms? Copy and Paste would be easy...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keeping the information on users and controls to hide in a Module. This will be easier to configure and to handle.

You also need a means of iterating not only through top-level controls but also controls nested on a container control, like a panel or tab-control. For this, you can create a reusable recursive extension method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module FormExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Iterator Function AllControls(ByVal parent As Control) As IEnumerable
        For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
            Yield c
            For Each nested As Control In c.AllControls()
                Yield nested
            Next
        Next
    End Function
End Module
```

In another module you can implement the logic

```
Module UserAccessControl
    ' Dictionary with users as key containing nested dictionaries with form names as key
    ' containing names of controls to be hidden in a HashSet.
    Private m_controlsToHide As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of String))) From
    {
        {"user", New Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of String)) From {
                    {"Form1", New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox1", "ComboBox2", "TextBox17"}},
                    {"Form2", New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox3", "Button1"}}
                }
        },
        {"account", New Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of String)) From {
                    {"Form1", New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox17"}},
                    {"Form2", New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox3", "Button1", "Button2"}}
                }
        }
    }

    Public Sub HideControls(ByVal user As String, ByVal form As Form)
        Dim userDict As Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of String))
        Dim controls As HashSet(Of String)

        If m_controlsToHide.TryGetValue(user, userDict) AndAlso
            userDict.TryGetValue(form.Name, controls) Then

            For Each control As Control In form.AllControls() _
                .Where(Function(c) controls.Contains(c.Name))

                control.Visible = False
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

If you prefer, you can also switch "user" and "form" and make the forms first level of the data structure.

Inside the form you can call

```
Public Sub New()
    InitizialeComponent()
    UserAccessControl.HideControls(userName, Me)
End Sub
```

---

By using a compound [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples) key we can flatten the data structure and get rid of one level of dictionary:

```
Private m_controlsToHide As New Dictionary(Of (String, String), HashSet(Of String)) From {
    {("user", "Form1"), New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox1", "ComboBox2", "TextBox17"}},
    {("user", "Form2"), New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox3", "Button1"}},
    {("account", "Form1"), New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox17"}},
    {("account", "Form2"), New HashSet(Of String) From {"TextBox3", "Button1", "Button2"}},
}

Public Sub HideControls(ByVal user As String, ByVal form As Form)
    Dim controls As HashSet(Of String)

    If m_controlsToHide.TryGetValue((user, form.Name), controls) Then
        For Each control As Control In form.AllControls() _
            .Where(Function(c) controls.Contains(c.Name))

            control.Visible = False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Instead of storing the access information in code, you could also store it in a database. I often have applications where super-users can change these settings from within the application. This is more flexible than hard-coding the information.

Comment: You operate on a different plane altogether! It is not exactly over my head just something I would never ever think of. What's wrong with panels.

Comment: Panels work only if the controls to be hidden are grouped together. These controls could also be spread around.